# Downgrade iPhone 4 baseband from 4.12.01

Tags: ios, jailbreak, unlock

Need help with downgrading an iPhone 4 (GSM) from baseband 4.12.01 to be able to unlock it for use with other operator than AT&T.

Have tried this guide ([Downgrade iPhone 4 Baseband 4.12.01 to 4.11.08 / 4.10.01 / 01.59.00](http://cydiajb.com/downgrade-iphone-4-baseband-4.12.01-to-4.11.08-4.10.01-01.59.00/)) but I only end up with an lower iOS version but no baseband downgrade

Do you know how to downgrade the baseband?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to downgrade the baseband on an iPhone (or any Apple device, the iPad being an acception but also rife with disaster).

The only way to downgrade the baseband is to install a previous version that is still being signed by Apple. For example, if they release 5.2 today, they would be signing 5.1 and 5.2. If 5.2 came with a newer baseband, it would be upgraded once you've installed that version. If you decided to revert immediately to 5.1, it would downgrade both, the OS and the baseband.

Apple typically leaves the signing window open for only a few days. Once it's closed, you cannot alter the baseband (even if you successfully downgrade the OS).